# getJSON to get html from cross domain

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, getjson

i want html from other domain so i am using $.getJson to get html but i am getting some problems.

code i am using is

```
 var site = "www.moneycontrol.com";
        var yql_url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=cbFunc';
        $.getJSON(yql_url, function (json) {
            $('#CurrencyData').html(json.results[0]);
        });
```

inside document.ready of jquery.
and in html i have a div

```
<div id="CurrencyData">
    </div>
```

When i run this code nothing shows up on my localhost but if i debug with firebug..after running this page i do get JSON and response result with all html from above site.

Now i am wondering if i am getting data in JSON then why it is not showing in div ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing JSON-P, jQuery creates the necessary callback function for you, ensuring the name isn't already in use, etc. E.g., it does the plumbing.

So it can do that, let jQuery control the name of the callback function. In your query string, change

```
&callback=cbFunc
```

to

```
&callback=?
```

jQuery will substitute in the name of the callback it creates.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/evobef/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/evobef/1/edit) (literally just what's in your question with the change above made)

Comment: if i change from &callback=cbFunc to &callback=? and changing $('#CurrencyData').html(json.results[0]); to  $('#CurrencyData').html(json); i get nothing not even in firebug also

Comment: @Spenzo: You're injecting a different page's HTML into your page. It's not surprising you get some errors doing that (many of them look like errors where script on the page is relying on things that aren't loaded on your page). You'll have to do some processing on the HTML you get back, but fundamentally, the above change does at least let you get the HTML.